# NER model for lyrics[rap]

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I am looking for any NER model train to extract entity from rap lyrics. Presently I am using Spacy models for NER, but there's a lot of misclassification. This is because spacy models are pretrained on newspaper articles. So, the initial question; Is there any model that I can use for NER on rap lyrics.

This is how the present spacy model classifying some of the words

> ('kanye west', 'GPE'),('2pac', 'PRODUCT'),('hoochie coochie', 'ORG'),('valley', 'LOC'),('talkin', 'NORP'),('nothin', 'PERSON'),('100k', 'PRODUCT')

(In case if u are wondering what lyrics are these, these are from Kendrick Lamar)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to generate your own training data, as the words you are trying to classify are very specific to the American rap industry, and most probably not covered by any existing nlp package.

Comment: could u be kind to tell me where would I start looking into that?

Comment: Check this blog post out: https://towardsdatascience.com/train-ner-with-custom-training-data-using-spacy-525ce748fab7